# Offsetting an element gives me the scrollbars but not the padding

Tags: html, css, css-position, padding

For some reason if I offset h2 even for few px or 0.x %, scrollbars shows up on my page, even tho there is still a lot of space left for h2. But when I add padding-left, scrollbars won't show up and everything is fine. I was trying to find why is this happening using dev tools, but no success. Any ideas?

Code:

```
h2 {
  font-family: "fira sans";
  color: #529aaf;
  position: relative;
  /*left: 50px; here if I leave left: x then I get scrollbars. If I change left to padding, I wont' get them.*/
}

.profile_container {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: 200px;
}

.cycle {
  background: orange;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  min-width: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background-image: url(images/8.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  margin-right: 18%;
  margin-top: 10px;
}


.cycle:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}

.chat_container {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  /*position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;*/

}

.chat_container img {
  padding: 5%;
  position: relative;
  width: 150px;
  min-width: 150px;
  top: -260px;
}

.chat_container > div {
  padding: 5.5%;
  position: relative;
  width: 150px;
  min-width: 150px;
  top: -240px;
  border-radius: 5%;
}

.chat_container > div {
  background: #e2e2e2;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

p:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}

.partners_container {
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.partners_container img {
  margin-top: 24px
}

<div class="row">
<div class="col col-12  background_row">
  <h2>Our customers happily shares their experiences...</h2>
  <section class="references">
  <div class="profile_container">
  <div class="cycle"></div>
    <div class="cycle"></div>
      <div class="cycle"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="chat_container">
    <!--<img src="images/chat.png" width="9%"></img>
        <img src="images/chat.png" width="9%"></img>
            <img src="images/chat.png" width="9%"></img>-->
            <div><p>Amazing product!</p></div>
            <div><p>I love it!</p></div>
            <div><p>So good so far. recommend really </p></div>
          </div>
</section>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you provide a working example or a link to your page?

Comment: @AndyTschiersch my codepen http://codepen.io/Limpuls/pen/rWamPz I can't host pictures on codepen, so you will see the mess, but you can still see H2 giving scrollbars when you edit h2 in css and switch between offsetting and padding. If it's still hard to understand, I can try to host the images

Comment: try removing the `left:50px` in your h2 css and just add `padding-left:56px` to get the same result offset

Comment: @GvM I know that left: 50px gives me scrollbars. What I'm asking is why does it give me scrollbars if there is still ton of space left. Even padding-left: 50px won't give me scrollbars while `left` does.

Comment: i see. its because your `h2` is displayed block and it's taking 100% of the parents width. make it `display:inline-block` so its width is as long as the text.

Comment: @GvM oh yeahh, how I didn't see that... Thanks!